# 'id' value not incrementing automatically using pydobc on MS SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm getting this error:

```
pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'XXXX.dbo.logs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
```

It happens when I want to push new rows to the table:

```
   sql = ''' INSERT INTO logs(name,ip,page,socket,date)
              VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) '''
```

The DB is hosted on Azure SQL database.
This is my code that I used to create table:

```
sql_create_table = """CREATE TABLE XXXX.dbo.logs 
                            (
                                id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                                name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                                page VARCHAR(150)  NOT NULL,
                                socket VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                                date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
                            ); """
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` specifies a 3-part name, which is not supported in Azure SQL Database. It seems the logs table you are actually inserting into has a different schema, without the `IDENTITY` property on the `id` column.

Comment: I had to create 3-part name table otherwise it asked me to provide SCHEMA name.

Comment: What is "it"? How are you running the script?

Comment: If it's an Azure SQL database, you probably should just be using 2 part naming and specifying the DB name in the connection string. Considering you use 1 part in one stament and 3 in the other, wouldn't be surprised you're communicating with 2 different databases.

Comment: @DanGuzman I use pyodbc to connect to the database its in the errors.  Could you tell me how should this connection look like?

Comment: @AlexT, I know little about pyodbc but found [this](https://gist.github.com/technetbytes/2720961ae365c02a0a248cc0a19db3ec) with a cursory internet search. The example does not qualify the table name with a database or schema, although I would expect the 2-part name `dbo.logs` to work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding " PRIMARY KEY ", after the "Identity...", and before " NOT NULL "

Comment: I wouldn't expect the primary key constraint to affect the identity value. It will only prevent dups.